Need help finding a replacement for this IC component
I can’t seem to find a replacement. All help appreciated

I'm betting it's a Silergy SY21605ABC but I can't confirm that yet because that datasheet is behind a registration process. I saw a similar part number and form factor that had a marking that started with HDxxx instead. This marking looks very ubiquitous with Silergy.

I believe the purpose of this is to step down voltage from a main 12V power supply to 5V for a beagle bone black.

Just got approved for datasheet the Silergy part I mentioned. It is in fact not the part I mentioned. Fairly confident that it's still a Silergy part, however. I cannot find it on their website so I want to say that this could be a private SKU for their customer.

@NicholasBoehm So if that regulator is not on a BeagleBone Black board, on which board it is then? Which board you bought?

Alibaba returns spare with same reference  'HB0gT' and package seems the same
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/BOM-of-electronic-components-Interface-chip_1600561587811.html
